# Changing label in GUI from thread in another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label in GUI in my main Form. From the Form when I press a button, a new Thread is created with a parameter, some things happen and in the end I want to update the label saying it is done. But I am getting a NullRefferenceException. How can I update it? I basically used the same code in a different project, I just did not start the Thread with a parameter. Here is my code:

GUI_logic.cs:

```
private void button_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UploadFile upload = new UploadFile();

        t_upload = new Thread(() => upload.startUpload(file));
        t_upload.Start();
} 

public static GUI_logic _GUI_l;

delegate void updateLabelStatusCallback(string text);
    public void updateLabelStatus(string message) {
        if (this.label_status.InvokeRequired) {
            updateLabelStatusCallback d = new updateLabelStatusCallback(updateLabelStatus);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { message });
        } else {
            this.label_status.Text = message;
        }
}
```

UploadFile.cs:

```
public void startUpload(OpenFileDialog file) {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        switch (ext) {
            case ".xml":
                parseXMLFile(file.FileName);
                break;
        }
}

private void parseXMLFile(string file) {
    I do stuff here
    ...

    ...
    //And now I want to update the label
    GUI_logic._GUI_l.updateLabelStatus("Done");
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code shows the `GUI_logic._GUI_l` variable being set, is it actually being set?

Comment: I am setting it in GUI_logic.cs under the button_upload_click if you mean that.

Comment: Which line is throwing the null reference exception ?

Comment: the line that tries to update it throwe the exception: `GUI_logic._GUI_l.updateLabelStatus("Done");` So how exactly can I fix that @Grant Winney ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer. Like the comments suggested, I did not instantiate the variable so I added `_GUI_l=this` in a code

```
public GUI_logic() {
        _GUI_l = this;
        InitializeComponent();
}
```